# How to use the arm global timer in linux kernel drivers?

Tags: linux, module, timer, arm, kernel

I'm writing a kernel module that shall use the arm global timer to read the counter value.
The Linux kernel provides a driver for ARM global timer defined in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.249/source/drivers/clocksource/arm_global_timer.c.
There is a static function that I would like to use it: **static u64 notrace _gt_counter_read(void)** or others that call it, for example:

```
    static u64 gt_counter_read(void)
    {
      return _gt_counter_read();
    }
```

but any of them are exported by the kernel.
The clocksource structure defines a read function, but I didn't figure out a way to use it. How can I do that?

Comment: I dont think they are supposed to be exported as they are modules. This clock has been abstracted as a linux clock source. The question is how to read a specific clock source in Linux.

Comment: @MadFred Perhaps the question could be summarized to this.. ;-) For while, to some this problem I created a header file with the function and included the export symbol in the source. But I believe that should be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Could you copy the code and create a new module? It looks very simple to me. Ideally you'd create a character device that could be opened or memory mapped.